# Material ui tabs goes in infinite loop when i Load my componenet in navigation Bar (appbar>tabspanel)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I am creating application for my school project and I am trying to use material ui in my application.

I am following official documentation through the website.

Here's the link I am following the [Code](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#ScrollableTabsButtonAuto.js).

I want to load new component when I click on the tab but i want the same navigation on the top so i can navigate to other pages.

here is the code I have been trying.

```
<div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static" color="default">
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          indicatorColor="primary"
          textColor="primary"
          variant="scrollable"
          scrollButtons="auto"
          aria-label="scrollable auto tabs example"
          centered="true"
        >
          <Tab label="Dashboard" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab label="User Manager" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <Tab label="Spot Manager" {...a11yProps(2)} />
          <Tab label="Statistics" {...a11yProps(3)} />
          <Tab label="Account Manager" {...a11yProps(4)} />
          <Tab label="Log Out" {...a11yProps(5)} />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}></TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        <Dashboard />{" "}
      </TabPanel>
```

My dashboard is just empty component like this

```
    <>
        <NavBar />
        <h1>Hi</h1>  
    </>
```

here is how it just gets loading [image]

after a while it shows kill page or wait

can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Did you check the console? What is `a11yProps`? Is it possible it's changing state?

Comment: [click here](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#ScrollableTabsButtonAuto.js) for full code.

Comment: ? That's a link to the Material.ui docs. I'm asking about a11yProps.

Comment: yes i tried console

Comment: @ChrisG   this is the function ```function a11yProps(index) {
  
  return {
    id: `scrollable-auto-tab-${index}`,
    "aria-controls": `scrollable-auto-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}```

Comment: Ok, looks fine. Usually, what causes a React app to hang is an infinite loop; it's when you accidentally change state inside render(), which causes a re-render, which changes state again, etc etc. Try removing components and adding them back in until you find the cause, there's not much I can do without seeing more of your code.

Comment: I added useHistory().push("/path") on onclick function on this line                                          ```    <Tab
            label="Dashboard"
            onClick={() => {
              history.push("/dashboard");
            }}
            {...a11yProps(0)}
          />                                                                                                                              ```  it's working now but the problem now is active tab color is not changing unlsess i double click it but thanks for your time  I really Appreciate

Comment: tried using the `Link` instead of pushing manually with `history.push()`?

Comment: @Rajiv doesn't work

Comment: can you reproduce your issue in [codesandbox](htttps://codesandbox.io)

Comment: I am sorry to say, I fixed my problem and I don't Have that version of code. But I am glad and appreciate your support to the community. Thank you so much Means a lot.

Comment: @Rajiv I posted the answer if you guys wan't to checkout, just for referance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just write simple code as I learend,

```
    <>
      <AppBar position="static" color="default">
        <Tabs>
          <Tab label="Dashboard" />
          <Tab label="User Manager" />
          <Tab label="Spot Manager" />
          <Tab label="Statistics" />
          <Tab label="Finance" />
          <Tab label="Log Out" />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      **{value === 0 && <Dashboard />}
      {value === 1 && <UserManager />}
      {value === 2 && <SpotManager />}
      {value === 3 && <Statistics />}
      {value === 4 && <Finance />}**
    </>
```

this highlighted Part will do the job,
Remember Tabs have index by themselves so don't worry like i didn's specify id or value how it will work.

You just match the index and load component you want to.

If you want to apply style, read documentation or watch youtube Modify  for example,

```
<Tabs value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          indicatorColor="primary"
          textColor="primary"
          variant="scrollable"
          scrollButtons="auto"
        >
///Your <Tab label="example /> goes here 
</Tabs>

//index condition goes here to show components.
```